# Помогите составить SQL-запрос для выборки из 3 таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем привет. Накидал пример для наглядности.
Я постарался подробно нарисовать на картинке что я хочу получить. Но проблема в том что значения при выводе из 3-х таблиц дублируются. И получается неправильная сумма! Вот пример + SQL запрос.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
SELECT Order.Id, Order.Customer, SUM(Order_position.Weight),
       SUM(Order_other.Price * Order_other.Value)
   FROM Order 
     LEFT JOIN 
        Order_position ON Order.Id = Order_position.Order_id 
     LEFT JOIN 
        Order_other ON Order.Id = Order_other.Order_id 
   WHERE Order.Id = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT O.Id, O.Customer,
       (select SUM(Weight) from Order_position
         where O.Id = Order_position.Order_id ) as Weight,
       (select SUM(Price * Value) from Order_other
         where O.Id = Order_other.Order_id) as Other
   FROM `Order` as O
  WHERE O.Id = 1
```

Вариант 2:

```
SELECT A.Id, A.Customer, A.Weight, SUM(Order_other.Price * Order_other.Value)
  FROM (
    SELECT O.Id, O.Customer, SUM(Order_position.Weight) as Weight
      FROM `Order` as O
      LEFT JOIN Order_position ON O.Id = Order_position.Order_id
     WHERE O.Id = 1
     GROUP BY O.Id, O.Customer
  ) A
  LEFT JOIN Order_other ON A.Id = Order_other.Order_id 
 GROUP BY A.Id, A.Customer, A.Weight
```

Comment: я выбрал 1 вариант! Спасибо